# bitcoin paper wallet--multiple addresses

Tags: paper-wallet

Is it is true that a paper wallet has only one address and can only have one address maximum?

I want to be 100% sure when I check my balance on blockchain.info that the money is there. If someone were to take my private key, could they generate a new address and transfer money without me seeing it (since I only check the address WRITTEN on the paper wallet)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, from 1 private key you can calculate exactly 1 public key, and from 1 public key you can calculate exactly 1 address.

But suppose the attacker could generate another address, addresses are only for receiving, so they could not send it "from" the address they generate.

To sign a bitcoin transaction, the private key is used directly, so there is no way you would not see it (on blockchain.info for example).

Also, if it were possible to generate a different "sending address", there would be no traceability or value in the bitcoin ledger and keeping track of the unspent outputs would be impossible.

Answer (score 3):

The bitcoin's wallet is made up of two keys, a public key and a private one. The general title of the wallet, where you can receive money from others, is exactly the opposite: it allows you to send your coins to others.
And of course your key, no one should know, so you do not steal easily, do not disclose this number to anyone.
Create a paper bitcoin wallet step-by-step.

here you can find in MY SITE more information regarding [How to create paper bitcoin wallet](https://www.tradingpeek.com/en/crypto/details/Crypto-learning/13/How-to-create-paper-bitcoin-wallet)

Comment: Please note if you want to promote your own product/blog you **must disclose your affiliation in the answer**, otherwise, your answer may be flagged as spam. If you are not affiliated with the site, I recommend you say so to prevent this. Please read [How to not be a spammer](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/help/promotion)

Comment: sorry, i am new in this site... regarding the a above link its connect to my site and i linked it because its answer the question. anyway i will read the rules